# How customize AlertDialog with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create a custom AlertDialog making use of Jetpack Compose. I need to put a colored bar for the title as well as different components such as text, radiobuttons ... The end goal is something like this:

[image]

In XML layout I know it could be done, but is it possible in Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Dialog instead of AlertDialog.

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Dialog(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.DialogProperties,kotlin.Function0)

Inside Dialog you can put any composables you want.

Here is a nice sample:

[Show custom alert dialog in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852110/show-custom-alert-dialog-in-jetpack-compose)