# Content in Dialog not visible

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've wrapped a `Dialog` in Compose, Android. However, things don't seem to show up. Not sure what I need to do here, to fix this properly for it to work naturally speaking. Because, I plan on using `inputs` and other stuff e.g., `buttons` etc.

```
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class, ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyDialog(
    openDialog: Boolean,
    closeDialog: () -> Unit,
) {
    if (openDialog) {
        Dialog(
            properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false),
            onDismissRequest = closeDialog,
            content = {
                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    topBar = {
                        SmallTopAppBar(
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp, 0.dp, 16.dp, 10.dp),
                            title = {
                                Text(
                                    text = "Add new item",
                                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium,
                                )
                            },
                            colors = TopAppBarDefaults.smallTopAppBarColors(
                                containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                            ),
                            navigationIcon = {
                                IconButton(onClick = {
                                    closeDialog()
                                }) {
                                    Icon(
                                        imageVector = Icons.Filled.Close,
                                        contentDescription = null
                                    )
                                }
                            },
                            actions = {
                                Text(
                                    "Save",
                                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
                                )
                            },
                        )
                    },
                ){
                    Text("Hello world!") // <-- Does not show up
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

**Produces:**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you are ignoring the `innerPadding` values which comes fro `Scaffold` . You should be using it as the padding for your outer composable as `Modifier.padding(it)`.

```
                   Text("Hello world!", modifier = Modifier.padding(it))
```

Above code should work . for further use Wrap the content in a container in this case `Column` .

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(it)
                    .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Text("Hello world!")
            }
```

to Show a dialog you do not have to pass the immutable state to Dialog composable i.e `openDialog: Boolean` .  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71841964/4168607) is better example how you should handle Dialog state ..