# Android Compose: Is there any way to dismiss dialog on click of “Done” key from keyboard

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, ime, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I'm new to Android compose. Is there any way to dismiss dialog on click of *Done* key from keyboard using ImeAction?

Currently below code is clearfocus on click of *Done* along with how to dismiss the dialog:

```kotlin
    TextField(
        value = text,
        onValueChange = {
            text = it
        },
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onDone = { focusRequester.requestFocus() }
        ),
        modifier = Modifier.onKeyEvent {
            if (it.nativeKeyEvent.keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                focusRequester.requestFocus()
                true
            }
            false
        }
    )
```

Comment: To dismiss the alert dialog?, if not please attach a screenshot for more clarity.

Comment: What kind of dialog?

Comment: there is a custom password dialog I need to dismiss onclick of onDone click which is  ImeAction

Comment: Then you are probably managing the state of that dialog with `MutableState<Boolean>`.
In that case just set that to false, or call the method you call to hide the dialog inside `onDone` method. Refer to the answer below.

Comment: Check Thracian's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside onDone set the flag you use to show dialog to false

```
var showDialog by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}

 onDone = { 
    focusRequester.requestFocus()
    showDialog = false
 }

if(showDialog) {
   AlerDialog(...)
}
```

You check out the link below to show dialogs

[Show custom alert dialog in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68852110/show-custom-alert-dialog-in-jetpack-compose)