# How to use material3 custom dialog in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to build `Alert Dialog` with **options** selection with rounded corners. I tried `Material 3` library `Alert Dialog` code. I was looking this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68853201) but getting weird errors. I have `BOM version` is `compose_bom = "2022.11.00"`

```
@Composable
fun DialogOptionsView() {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {}
    ) {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .wrapContentWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.large
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

**Error** I am  getting

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
DialogProperties
Found:
() → Unit
```

**Error Image**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BOM package contains only **stable versions** of the different Compose libraries.
In particular the BOM `2022.11.00` contains the `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1`

To use the [`content`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68853201) parameter with `AlertDialog` you have to use at least the version `1.1.0-alpha04` of M3.

In your `build.gradle` use:

```
dependencies {
    // Import the Compose BOM
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.01.00')

    // Override Material Design 3 library version with a pre-release version
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha05'

   //...
}
```

Also check the BOM to libraries [mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping).

Comment: can we use content without alpha version of material3?

Comment: I can't use alpha beta version in the project..

Comment: @VivekModi `AlertDialog` with the `content` variant exists only starting from M3 `1.1.0-alpha04` and the `1.1.0` is currently in an alpha release. Then you can't use it. You can use the other solution described in the same answer.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try this one