# Jetpack Compose-AlertDialog: "Cannot find a parameter with this name: icon"

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to implement a Jetpack Compose-AlertDialog according to this: [Android-Documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/dialog#alert)

```
 AlertDialog(onDismissRequest = {},
            backgroundColor = Color.LightGray,
            icon = Icons.Default.Info, // Causes 'Cannot find parameter' error!
            title = { /* ... */
```

Android-Studio marks the icon-parameter as erroneous and displays "*Cannot find a parameter with this name: icon*" as hint.
The Icon-parameter is indeed missing, when I navigate to the function-definition.

```
@Composable
fun AlertDialog(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    confirmButton: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    dismissButton: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    title: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    text: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.medium,
    backgroundColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface,
    contentColor: Color = contentColorFor(backgroundColor),
    properties: DialogProperties = DialogProperties()
) { /* ... */
```

**What's this variation between the official documentation and the actual function-definition? Respectively: What goes wrong here?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two versions of material design - version 2 and version 3. While [specs for dialog](https://m3.material.io/components/dialogs/specs) in version 3 mentions icon, [specs for dialog](https://m2.material.io/components/dialogs) in version 2 does not.

There are corresponding versions of compose material library. Material 2 [AlertDialog](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/2a4d6a4ee3d5072263a5a71e3e24146a91af66e2:compose/material/material/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/AndroidAlertDialog.android.kt;l=64) is the one you copied and doesn't have icon, Material 3 [AlertDialog](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/f6bc21bf9af8178fcb343d0a2d074178f30d7722:compose/material3/material3/src/androidMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/AndroidAlertDialog.android.kt;l=78) has optional `icon` parameter according to specs.

So your problem is that you are using material 2 in your app, but looking at the documentation of material 3.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP and as far as I can tell, I'm only referencing material 3 (import androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialog). Any other places to look?

Comment: Found it! Looks like I had outdated Compose BOM (https://stackoverflow.com/a/75327539/9107045). I updated to the latest available.